# ¿Qué hacer con la etiqueta id?

Tags: discusión, etiquetas

Acabo de ver una edición sugerida en la que intentaban añadir la etiqueta [id](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/id).

Veo las preguntas asociadas y... pues sí, se trata de identificadores de algo. De un registro, de un elemento en el DOM o en un documento HTML, de un registro de BD.

Sin embargo, no me da para decir que lo quitemos o no, que tampoco se ha usado mucho. Pero tampoco sé para qué pueda servir el mantenerlo vivo.

¿Qué opinan?

Comment: Yo opino que habría que eliminarla. No le veo ningun sentido, y menos con una orientación de uso específica. En SO [también se propuso](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/384601/579895)

Comment: De acuerdo con @Pikoh. El problema es que siempre acaba recreándose https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/id

Comment: No si la quemamos @fedorqui

Comment: @Pikoh cierto. Me encantaría ver ese espectáculo, que imagino más o menos así: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FEihD.jpg, tú de jinete gatuno ([fuente](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/183868/209901))

Comment: @fedorqui'SOdejadedañar' si nadie se opone lo verás ( exceptuandome a mi de jinete gatuno, claro ;) )

Comment: Me anima el espíritu de @Pikoh. Un día de estos quemamos VBA y PHP (y no precísamente las etiquetas) :D

Comment: Parece no ser una etiqueta, debería eliminarse como opina @Pikoh.